# Can we use regex to find all nodes with specific attribute value using libxml2?

Tags: html, c, parsing, xml-parsing, libxml2

Hello I'm using libxml2 to parse the HTML. I want to check the given node has specific attribute or not.

But in my case I want to check for nodes with specific attribute(**Can I provide regex matching with multiple attribute instead of attribute name?**)

libxml2 API used to check whether the give node has that attribute or not?

```
xmlAttrPtr xmlHasProp(const xmlNode * node, 
                      const xmlChar * name)
```

I'm looking for the way like below:

```
xmlAttrPtr xmlHasProp(const xmlNode * node, 
                      const char * attributeNameRegex)
```

So that I can check for nodes with multiple attribute.
e.g. I want to check for node has "onClick" or "onmouseover" or "onmouseclick" kind of attribute or not?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use XPath, but libxml2 supports neither XPath 2.0 nor the EXSLT regex extension. libxml2 comes with its [own XML Schemas compatible regex module](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlregexp.html), though. Something like the following should work:

```
int xmlHasMatchingProp(const xmlNode *node,
                       const xmlChar *attrNameRegex) {
    xmlRegexpPtr regex;
    xmlAttrPtr attr;

    if (node == NULL || node->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        return 0;

    regex = xmlRegexpCompile(attrNameRegex);
    if (regex == NULL)
        return 0;

    for (attr = node->properties; attr != NULL; attr = attr->next) {
        if (xmlRegexpExec(regex, attr->name) == 1)
            break;
    }

    xmlRegFreeRegexp(regex);
    return attr ? 1 : 0;
}
```

But if you only want to check whether an attribute name starts with "on", you can simplify the code above, using [xmlStrncasecmp](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html#xmlStrncasecmp) for example:

```
for (attr = node->properties; attr != NULL; attr = attr->next) {
    if (xmlStrncasecmp(attr->name, "on", 2) == 0)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but with you solution also we have iterate over all the nodes check attribute of each node with our regex.  I'm looking for a way in which, I will get all nodes has attribute matching with specific regex. i.e. regex : "on*" . Can we do that?

Comment: @BSalunke You can easily adjust my code to achieve what you want. If you run into problems, you can always aks a new question.

Comment: How can this be done progressively using `xmlRegNewExecCtxt` and a callback? I have been scouring the internet trying to find an example. I want the matches from the regex.